# How to validate Roll number and contact Number in servlet?

Tags: java, validation, servlets

This is my post method.I am going to validate user inputs such as Name,Rollnumber(should be integer and it has 4 digits) ,department and contact number(Integer & 10 digits)

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
     response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String ename=request.getParameter("name");
    int erollno=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rollno"));
    String edepartment=request.getParameter("department");
    int enumber=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("contactnumber"));

    if(ename.equals("")){
        out.println("Enter Valid details..Please go Back");
    }
    //Help needed here    

    else {

    try {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("Details You entered</br>");
        out.println("NAME           ="+ename +"<br>");
        out.println("ROLL NO        ="+erollno+"<br>");
        out.println("Department     ="+edepartment+"<br>");
        out.println("Contact Number ="+enumber);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

If I give input other than integer it produces number format exception. I am stuck at //help needed here point onwards.I must validate roll number and contact number and make sure they provide integer and with the no.of digits required for that fields. How can I validate and cathch the exceptions.

Comment: there are multiple ways, you can use regular expressions to validate data, or move your number checking to another method and duck exception there.

Comment: Thanks I found another way